# Reference built-in drawable reporting "No resource found that matches the given name"

Tags: android, xamarin, resources

This seems like a question that should already be answered many times, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I've suggestions for similar errors, but none work. I'm trying to follow some instructions I found at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/ for adding a toolbar to an app. I ended up with a file called MainMenu.xml in my Resources\menu directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--For all properties see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_login"
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_save"
         android:title="Login"/>

</menu>
```

But when I build. I receive an error:

> 1: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_action_content_save').

**Edit:** I see I missed the bit about extracting a zip file, but I thought there were some built-in resources in the SDK/Android system that could be referenced. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For built-in resources, you need to include `android:` in front of the drawable directory, and the name of the save icon for use in a menu is `ic_menu_save`:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
```

That said, some resources indicate that it is not advised to use system resources because they may change. They encourage copying them into your project for consistency on future versions of Android. My personal opinion is that for such generic functions like save, if they're going to change the icon, I want my app to follow along.